# ExtJS throwing Invalid domNode reference or an id of an existing domNode: null when trying to bind one element to the config of another

Tags: javascript, dom, extjs

For this code with the bind part not commented I get the error message which I post below the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="./ext-all-debug.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var resultsPanel = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
      title: 'Results',
      width: 600,
      height: 400,
      border: true,
      layout: {
          type: 'vbox',       // Arrange child items vertically
          align: 'stretch',    // Each takes up full width
          padding: 5
      },
      items: [{               // Results grid specified as a config object with an xtype of 'grid'
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'button1',
          pressed: false,
          reference: 'button1',
          listeners : {
              click: { fn: function(){ alert("heheh");}}
          }
      },
      {
          xtype: 'button',
          text: 'button2',
          bind: {
              hidden: '{!button1.pressed}',
          }
      }
    ]
});
Ext.onReady(function () {
    resultsPanel.render(Ext.getBody());
   }, this, {delay: 1000});
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

following error message:

```
[E] Ext.dom.Element.constructor(): Invalid domNode reference or an id of an existing domNode: null ext-all-debug.js:10375:31
extPanel.html:34
```

When I remove the bind part from the code then everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `button1` you must add:

```
enableToggle: true,
```

`pressed` is only available for toggle buttons.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm one step ahead, because now I get
_Cannot use bind config without a viewModel_

Comment: That's something :-) Now add to the definition of `panel`:

`viewModel: true,`

Comment: Do you have an idea why this code snippet does not work?
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3k4g

Comment: Because JS doesn't forgive casing errors: use `viewModel` (capital M) instead of `viewmodel`. Just tried it, it works.

Comment: For the click, you can replace the listener with a handler, like `handler: function() {alert('hehe');}`